# When and where did Mary Thomas b. abt 1793 in Port of Menteith, Dunbartonshire marry her (first) Hutcheson husband and what was his forename?

Tags: marriage-records, scotland, 1820s, 1810s

Who was the Hutcheson or Hutchison who could have married a Mary Thomas, possibly in Barony, Glasgow, Lanarkshire around 1810-1820?

We now know that Mary died in Davidson, Tennessee in 1868.  Some time before the discovery of her death and burial dates by another Thomas family researcher, I found her in Tennessee in the 1860 census, along with her second husband Robert Mcguigin, living in the household of Neil Hutchison, who seems to have been her only child.

Mary married her second husband Robert Mcguigin (spelt McQuiben) 17th November 1838, Gorbals, Glasgow. The record of Mary's second marriage (Scotland Select Marriages, 1561-1910) gives her as Mary Thomas but, it was common for Scottish women in widowhood to revert to their maiden names. (Mary was descended from a family of Thomases who lived in Stirlingshire, Perthshire and Dunbartonshire in the 18th and 19th centuries. I am descended from her brother Walter. We know a great deal about other members of the Thomas family but less about Mary.)

We have never been able to pin down the name and dates of her first husband and her marriage to him. This may well have been because Mary's family of origin seemed to veer between conventional Presbyterian parish churches and less formal congregations whose records are harder to find when they exist at all. Given that Mary seems to have had only one child (who lived to adulthood, anyway) by her Hutchinson husband, it may be that he, the husband, died early in their marriage, perhaps because of some accident or maybe from illness. If you have a Hutchison forebear  who married a Mary in the early 1800s, 1810-1823, perhaps think about whether he could be this chap.

Comment: I've re-worded your opening sentence to become a question, because there was otherwise no question mark in your question body, and also to emphasize that the question is for anybody willing to try and answer it rather than seeking to connect with cousins.  The latter can of course happen when questions are answered but that should be an indirect benefit to question askers.

Comment: Do you have Mary's second (Mcguigin) marriage record?  If so, does it record her previous surname as being Hutchinson or Thomas?

Comment: Thanks for your interest PolyGeo.The record of Mary's second marriage (Scotland Select Marriages, 1561-1910) gives her as Mary Thomas but, as you probably know, it was common for Scottish women in widowhood to revert to their maiden names.

Comment: If you have a link to that 1860 Census record, and a date for her second marriage I think it would be helpful to [edit] those into your question too.

Comment: I have the 1860 census record for Davidson, Tennessee (it came from Ancestry) but can't find a way to finagle the link, unfortunately.Still, anyone interested should be able to find it via Ancestry.

Comment: The history of the Scottish churches is [complicated](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8f/Churches_of_Scotland_timeline.svg), but many of the records are held either by the [National Archives of Scotland](http://www.gla.ac.uk/myglasgow/archives/news/dunaskinnews200207/sourcesforscottishchurchhistoryinthenas/), or Local Authority Archives which are included on the NAS catalogue. The records themselves are not available online, but catalogues of Church records collections are available on the NAS online catalogue.